# Dynamic aggregation column input reference in Spotfire TERR data function

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

How can I make a dropdown menu that allows me to reference different columns and change the column reference of a data function in Spotfire's TERR/R?

I am creating 2D cross plots of data, using TERR data function to overlay the average profile line of the data on top of the individual profile lines. I am trying to add the ability to toggle between different normalizations. I want to be able to see data and the average of data over time normalization, pressure normalization, etc, etc. Without having to go into the data function and change the column name reference every time I want to change.

I know how to make the dropdown in the text area and reference each visualization, so those change automatically, but I still can't figure out how to make the TERR data input column to change dynamically with the dropdown menu selection so that the average line also changes.

There must be some way to simply say I want whatever is in the document property to be the "group by" column in the TERR data function to perform aggregations against. (I'm using the R package dplyr to do various simple statistical aggregations on data)

Thanks for the help!